# JSon.NET deserializing object doesn't work

Tags: c#, json, sockets, serialization, json.net

So I have a Client-Server application that is using this class for communication, it contains an object so I can send any kind of data between server and client:

```
        public class comObj
        {
            public eDisconnectedReason dcReason;
            public object payload;
        }
```

Before sending it through the Socket I will serialize it using JSon.Net, e.g.:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((new Common.comObj() { dcReason = Server.disconnectedReason, payload = Data }), Formatting.None);
```

now the server receives exactly the string that was sent by the client:

```
sent string: "{\"dcReason\":4,\"payload\":{\"msg\":\"hi\"}}"
received string: "{\"dcReason\":4,\"payload\":{\"msg\":\"hi\"}}"
```

however when I try to deserialize the received string into the original comObj:

```
Common.comObj rcvdObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Common.comObj>(rcvdString);
```

rcvdObj.payload is of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject instead of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start by considering your JSON input:

```
{
    "dcReason": 4,
    "payload": {
        "msg": "hi"
    }
}
```

Using Json.NET you have two key ways of deserializing JSON data.  You can:

1. Deserialize it into a *specific* concrete type
2. You can deserialize it into the generic `JToken` type.  (In your case, it instantiates a `JObject` -- a subclass of `JToken` -- because JSON.Net recognized that the JSON input specified an object, as opposed to a primitive type or an array)

In your case, you actually ended up with a hybrid of both approaches.  Since you specified a specific type for the root object, it returned an instance of `comObj`.  Since you merely specified `object` as the type of the property `payload`, Json.NET did its best and simply reverted to option 2) and gave you an instance of `JObject`, which contains the data such as `msg`.

You have two options to solve your problem.  You can:

- Interrogate the `payload` property as a `JObject`, like you would have had to do for the entire JSON body if you had not used option 1).
- Define a concrete type to represent the `payload` property.  I *strongly* recommend this approach, as it is considerably more typesafe and also easier to work with.

To achieve the former, you can use faclities such as `o["msg"]` -- essentially like a dictionary.

To achieve the latter -- which I would recommmend -- simply define a type for `payload`.  In other words, change you code to:

```
    public class comObj
    {
        public eDisconnectedReason dcReason;
        public Payload payload;
    }

    public class Payload 
    {
        public string msg { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when you deserialize your JSON, you'll be able to use the syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine(rcvdObj.payload.msg);
```

And -- importantly -- if you later decide to rename `msg` in your JSON payload to, say, `message` you will be able to properly *refactor* the property `msg` of payload to `message` and expect all usages to be fixed.  This is obviously less robust when using strings.